# How to allow a Boolean index only be unique for True

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table that I'm doing logical deletes on. I have a column `Name` and a column `Is_Active`. `Name` is a `varchar` and `Is_active` is a `bool`.

I can't make `Name` unique because there will be multiple rows that have the same name. Where `Is_Active == False`.

I need to make sure that at any time there is only one record for a `Name` where `Is_Active == True`.

Is there a way I can do this ? Or can anybody suggest a better way ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a unique filtered index at database level:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_EmployeeName
ON Employee (Name)
WHERE Is_Active = 1
```

The above index will not allow duplicate records like `('Bob', 1)`. It will allow though records like `('Bob', 1)`, `('Bob', 0)` to co-exist in your database.

Answer (score 6):

Allow a Filtered Index having condition of "not being 0". 0 representing false. This way, only one true value can exist. You won't have to create nullable column, just ignore the false value using filter.

Example of EF Core:

```
entity.HasIndex(x => new {x.ArticleId, x.IsActive}).IsUnique().HasFilter("[IsActive] != 0");
```

It's not a workaround so I love it!

Answer (score 0):

When you want multiple rows for a unique name and also you want to have at most one of them be active, I suggest you this solution:
(I think, when you have more than one active name, only last or recent one should active)

```
UPDATE dt
SET dt.Is_Active = 0
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Is_Active DESC) As Rn
    FROM 
        Employee  e) dt
WHERE 
    Is_Active = 1 And Rn > 1
```